# Facebook login feature advantage?

Tags: facebook, authentication

I came across one tricky thing while login into Facebook. If we reverse the character of password from uppercase to lowercase or vice versa, we can successfully login into facebook.

Like if my actual password is stackOverflow and I enter STACKoVERFLOW (reverse lowercase to uppercase and vise versa), I am able to login successfully.

Now, my question Is this a bug in Facebook or If this is not a bug, what is the advantage of these feature ?

Note: You can try the same, it will work for everyone.

Comment: Maybe so that if a user leaves `CAPSLOCK` on accidentally they can still login

Comment: Yes, exactly for that reason. Facebook has implemented it this way deliberately. They figured the trade-off in security is acceptable compared to the benefits for users. (I think you need to switch all upper- to lowercase characters and vice versa at the same time - so basically it just “doubles” the number of accepted password, from one to two.)

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68013/facebook-password-lowercase-and-uppercase

Comment: Nathan@ See even if user accidentally keeps the CAPSLOCK on, it wont work.

Let your password is : aBc and you keep capslock on and entered ABC, it wont allow you to login. You need to enter AbC for successful login.

Comment: @AjayYadav correct, but if you **unknowingly** have CAPSLOCK on and you type your password normally, capitalization will be reversed